# How can I get a count of particular element in a datatable?

Tags: vb.net, linq

So have a `DataTable` which has one column named as `DATE` which has a string `format`. I got a most Occurrence date in the column and stored it in a variable `DateMax2` but I want `count` as well.
However, when I try to get the `count` it is returning the row count of the `DataTable`.

Code:

```
var MaxOccur2 = (From d In FilterDT1.AsEnumerable Select DateMax2).ToArray
writeline(MaxOccur2.Count.ToString)
```

Comment: *"one column named as "DATE" which has a string format"*. WHYYYYYYYYY???!!! Why would you do such a thing? Do you store integer values as `Strings` or as `Integers`? I'm going to guess the latter. Why, then, would you not store dates as `Dates`? That data type doesn't exist for no reason.

Comment: In UiPath when we extract a Table from a web site. The ```ExtractedDataTable``` has DataTable format and it's element has a ```String``` format but you we can change the format of it's element as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.

```vb
Dim groups = From row In FilterDT1
             Group row By Key = row.Field(Of String)("DateColumn") Into Group
             Select DateValue = Key, Count = Group.Count()
Dim maxGroup = groups.OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.Count).First()

Console.WriteLine($"The most common DateColumn value is {maxGroup.DateValue}, which appeared {maxGroup.Count} times.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly stolen from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9499a619-6aba-4992-a073-4a47a035c11d/how-to-find-the-mode-of-an-array-of-numbers?forum=vbgeneral

How did you get the mode without a count?

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dates = {"3/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "3/1/2020", "4/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "1/1/2020"}
    Dim counts = dates.GroupBy(Function(n) n).Select(Function(g) New With {.Date = g.Key, .Quantity = g.Count})

    For Each count In counts
        Debug.WriteLine(count.Date & ": " & count.Quantity)
    Next

    Dim mode = dates.GroupBy(Function(n) n).Select(Function(g) New With {.Date = g.Key, .Quantity = g.Count}).OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Quantity).FirstOrDefault
    Debug.WriteLine($"Mode is: {mode.Date} Number of occurances: {mode.Quantity}")
End Sub
```